# Добавление записи и получение последней добавленной записи в одином запросе

Tags: mysql

Как уложить добавление записи и получение последней добавленной записи в один запрос?
Что-то вида

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM (INSERT ...)
```

Comment: Сначала сделать инсерт, поставить точку с запятой и сделать селект. Не?

Comment: @ReinRaus так же не интересно)))

Comment: @Palmervan, ну если только ради интереса :)  
Хотелось бы увидеть как это можно сколотить костылями в один запрос :)

Comment: Фишка в том, что некоторые прокси и... например Navicat... после деления точкой с запятой начинают возвращать всегда LAST_INSERT_ID() = 0. Как-то хитро они делят это на запросы и у каждого запроса почему-то случается свой SESSION_ID(), если я правильно понял причину.
В общем в голом mysql это работает, а в связке как мне надо уже совершенно не работает и приходится после инсерта делать монструозные выборки "а что же мы добавили"

Comment: Да не получится. Полюбому нужно делать либо несколько запросов, либо хранимую процедуру.

Answer (score 1):

Костыль, но другого варианта вижу. Попробуйте обмануть Navicat. Используйте DELIMITER.

```
DELIMITER $$
INSERT INTO ...$$
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Попробовал.
При выполнении в поле Message навикат честно делит его на два запроса, по обоим и выдаёт статистику
[SQL] 
INSERT INTO product SET 
 model = '1634231168_142672029',
 sku = '1634231168_142672029',
 quantity = '15',
 manufacturer_id = '253',
 price = '137.25',
 weight = '0',
 weight_class_id = 1,
 length_class_id = 1,
 stock_status_id = '7',
 `status` = '1',
 tax_class_id = '0',
 location = '',
 sort_order = '1',
 date_available = NOW(),
 date_added = NOW(),
 date_modified = NOW();
Affected rows: 1
Time: 0.439s

[SQL] 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
Affected rows: 0
Time: 0.602s

Увы :(

Comment: А если создать хранимую процедуру:  В ней делать вставку данных и возвращать выборку?

Comment: Как-то я вообще с хранимками не работал и не представляю, как будет выглядеть хранимка, у которой полностью меняется запрос insert каждый раз (а писать уникальную для каждой таблицы при моём количестве таблиц - мучительно долго и глючно-опечатывательно)

Answer (score 1):

> Как-то хитро они делят это на запросы
> и у каждого запроса почему-то
> случается свой SESSION_ID()

Cкорее всего это значит, что запросы исполняются в разных транзакциях, т.е. работа идёт в режиме "autocommit". Надо бы его отключить и работать в транзакционном режиме :)

Comment: В autocommit-режиме выполняются все запросы, если они не в транзакции. Проблема, похоже, в самом navicat. Он делит скрипт на отдельные SQL-запросы и через php-прокси выполняет эти запросы на сервере. Каждое обращение через прокси создает отдельное подключение к MySQL, а LAST_INSERT_ID() работает только в рамках одного подключения.

Comment: @QuAzi, а действительно, попробуй завернуть свой SQL в BEGIN - COMMIT. Может быть тогда navicat отправит весь скрипт через одно подключение. Иначе стоит смотреть в сторону других ide для MySQL. Например dbForge Studio.

Comment: Пробовал в BEGIN...COMMIT; - фигня не исчезла. Вопрос то не в IDE, а в "и через php-прокси выполняет эти запросы на сервере", через который я обязан работать и в поведении он совпадает с навикатом.

Comment: Предполагал что navicat умный, и если запросы завернуты в транзакцию то он отправит их одним пакетом, и выполнит в рамках одного подключения. Ошибался. Меняй IDE.

Comment: Шут с ним с IDE, как мне на C# работать с БД при условии что я упираюсь в точно такое же ограничение ? :(